# How can an intelligent magic lance change what type of weapon it is?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, magic-items, dnd-3e

I'm looking for any sort of ability to add onto an intelligent magical lance that will allow it to change into other weapons.  Whether this is something like making it "wear" a ring of Polymorph Any Object to an ability like Changeling for Spears.  Biggest reason behind this is that... well... noone uses bloody lances in the party.  It also doesn't help that the one character without a melee weapon is kinda small to be trying to wield a medium sized full jousting lance (he's still a medium sized creature, but weak and small).  Also, this is going to be considered an independent character unless being wielded by someone, it can take class levels, so if a class has something particularly in an early level that might somehow be of use, let me know.

Comment: Hmm... has someone been reading *Words of Radiance*? ;)

Comment: What level is the game?

Comment: We're at lv8ish, so the assigned WBL for creating the spear is 28k.

Answer (score 8):

The *Changeling* enhancement (MIC, p.31) allows the enchanted spear, shortspear o longspearlance to change to a spear (two-handed), a shortspear (one-handed), or a longspear (two-handed) *sized appropriately for you*.

The *Morphing* enhancement (MIC, p.39) turns your changeling weapon into a weapon of your choice, but must be of the same size and type (light, one-handed, two-handed).

Using both in this order allows you to morph a spear into any non-light weapon of your size.
Using these in the opposite order allows you to turn a lance into a spear and then use changeling on it.

The *Sizing* enhancement (MIC, p.43) further adds versatility, allowing you to get a smaller weapon so that you can use it as a light weapon (with a -2 penalty to hit) or a bigger weapon to use with feats and class features intended for wielding oversized weapons.

Comment: While this seems a little off the deep end I can see if it'll fly with the DM.  The main issue is that the Changeling is restricted to spears so I may not be able to apply it to a lance.  I'll see if he'll allow it though thanks for the idea :)

Comment: Before you run it by your DM, keep in mind that the MIC is horrendously broken. Particularly relevant to you, is that the morphing enhancment is horrendously broken - it means that your lance becomes able to overcome DR bludgeoning and slashing, gives it a range incremement of 110 ft, gives you the ability to make trip attempts with nice bonuses and allows you to attack someone right next to you while not charging and do decent damage. For a plus 1 bonus, I would say morphing only to a greatsword. For proper morphing, you should suggest more than a +1

Comment: @Dorian pffft I always forget lances and spears are two different weapons in English. Then again if nobody can use a lance why putting a lance and not a spear in the adventure?

Comment: @Scott You realize it's a standard action to change the weapon from one weapon into another *via* the weapon special ability *morphing*, right? And that the weapon can't be *all* weapons at once, right?

Comment: Also, the DM has ruled "Morphing weapons do not carry other enchantments to new form."  Someone told me to check the house rules :(  That rules out morphing altogether, but it's still a good option for others.

Answer (score 7):

Give the weapon the *Morphing* enhancement, from the Magic Item Compendium (page 39).

The enhancement allows the wielder of the weapon to change it into another weapon of the same size and type as a standard action. I think it'd be reasonable to allow an intelligent weapon to change itself.

Comment: OP might also want to consider the Transmuting property(from the same book), which allows the weapon to adapt it's physical element so as to bypass damage reduction as it sounds thematically appropriate

Comment: That seems almost perfect. The limitation on it being only to the same type though is a bit of a downer.  Has to stay a 2handed weapon still then.

As for Transmuting, it is a very useful ability but the drawback on that would be that I'm dealing with something that already has a +3 bonus, and even increasing it to a +4 bonus with Morphing is going to be quite expensive.

Answer (score 4):

If your sole reason for the shift is so that a non-lance character can claim it, just **give it an extra story-based ability to change its form once per wielder**. There's no reason to use up a property or enhancement unless you want it to have the power to change on the fly. It's already an intelligent item; they're allowed to break the rules a bit.

Comment: Hmm... Not sure if the DM would like that but once I get a chance to talk to him I'm definitely going to bring that up lol.

Answer (score 3):

An old question, but it surprises me that no one brought up the Rod of Lordly Might.

Turning the item into a full Rod of Lordly Might is probably overkill.

However, its primary function is swapping between weapon types (and magic traits) at the press of a button.

I don't know what the abilities of your lance are (except intelligence) so, as an example, you could allow it to switch between:

- Spear/Lance : +1 Wounding
- Javalin     : +2 Returning
- Mace        : +1 Flaming Ghost Touch
- Long Sword  : +2 Frost

Comment: Hmm, this was a long time ago and the campaign has since ended, but thanks for the input.  I didn't think of that myself.  If a similar situation comes up again in the future I will remember it.